# Return true of false confirmation dialog using JQuery UI dialog

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am going to submit a form after validating the form as follows,  here first I use a ajax post and check whether duplicate values are exist if exist ajax will return html code else return 'false'. Dialog box should popup if ajax return is a 'html code'. If ajax return is false **form_validate()** should return true. Which means no duplicates, form will submit for insert data. If user clicked Ok on the Dialog box, **form_validate()** should return true which means there are duplicates, form will submit for update data. If user clicked Cancel **form_validate()** should return false which means form will not submit. I am working on this hours but couldn't figure it out. Plz Help.

```
   function form_validate(){

         $.post('index.php',{ .....

                             },function(result){ 

                                if(result!='false'){
                                  $('<div></div>')
                                          .html(result+'<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
                                          .dialog({
                                                         buttons : {
                                                                "OK": function() { 
                                                                   $(this).dialog("close");                       
                                                                   return true;
                                                                 }, "Cancel": function() {
                                                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                                                         return false;
                                                                 }
                                 }
                                   }


             });



        }
```

**`<form>` Tag**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm" onsubmit="return validate_form();" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function form_validation(){
             $.post
              .....
              .....
            ,function(result){        



                           if(result!='false'){
                               $('<div></div>')   
                                      .html(result+'<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')   
                                      .dialog({   
                                   buttons : {
                                        "OK": function() { 
                                              $(this).dialog("close");                       
                                              $('#adminForm3').submit();
                                        }, "Cancel": function() {
                                              $(this).dialog("close");
                                        }
                                   }});
                           }
                           else{                                  
                               $('#adminForm3').submit();
                           }
                           return ;

                           });
return false;
}
```

add form id as adminForm3. This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return data from async requests - you need to handle that with callbacks. I'm not familiar with jQuery UI, so I'm not sure if it's possible to attach an "onClose" handler to the dialog, to which you can pass the `true` or `false` values.